# Right(S,2) vs Strings.Right(S,2)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Using VB dot net & Visual Studio 2010, I have a string and I want to grab the two right-most characters. So I go to the `Right()` function, which will do ***exactly*** that.  But in the project where I'm working, that isn't recognized, so I dutifully insert at the top of the form

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

But that's still not *quite* enough... I have to use `Strings.Right(S,2)` in order to avoid an error.  I know I have other projects that work with just using `Right()` without the `Strings.` in front, but I'm not sure what setting is different in those that avoids the need for the extra qualifier.

What can be changed so that `Right(S,2)` will work in this project?

**EDIT**: the error that I was getting without the `Strings.` qualifier is

> 'Public ReadOnly Property Right as Integer' has no parameters and its
>   return type cannot be indexed.

The Intellisense for "Right" as I start to type it says:

> Gets the distance, in pixels, between the right edge of the control
>   and the left edge of its container's client area

-- which is obviously not about string manipulations.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) say: "If used in a Windows Form, or any other class that has a Right property, you must fully qualify the function with Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right."  Could that be the issue?

Comment: If you quoted the text of the error in your question, I'd gladly vote up your question, because it's a good question which will likely be useful to other people.  But since you don't say what the error actually is, I can't in good conscience do so.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Good point -- edited to include the error message itself.

Comment: @Meta-Knight  Edited to include the error message.

Comment: @Mark  I think you're correct, as Blackwood explains in the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Right` function is defined in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings`. It is possible that you are getting this error in a Form class in a Windows Forms project, and when you simply type `Right(S,2)`, the compiler thinks you are calling the Right property of the Form class. I believe your choices are to move the code somewhere outside the Form class, or to qualify the call with `Strings.Right`.

Simply importing `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings` in your Form class won't help as the reference to `Right` will still be ambiguous.

Comment: That makes complete sense -- the other places that I use Right() by itself are in modules, not inside a From class.  But this project is all inside a Form, so that's exactly what's going on.  Thanks for your help!